# Looping through a JSON array and replacing the values if they are NULL

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an array of JSON coming from my controller

```
<%= raw @visits %>
```

[image]

I simply want to loop through this, and if the "name" is null then replace it with the string "Unknown". Currently this fails.

```
var withNull = <%= raw @visits %>;

var noNull = $.each(withNull, function(obj) {
    if(obj.name ==  null) {
        obj.name = "Unknown";
    }
});
```

Comment: Fails how? None of your names is null. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Correct in this particular case but occasionally the browser is not logged properly and when I graph this data I have a group with no name. Inspecting the data shows that in these cases the name is null. I want to add the name 'Unknown' to those cases. When I say fail, what I mean is that I fail to assign the name 'Unknown' to those objects whose name is null. Simple, but I'm having some difficulty

Comment: Can you step through the code line by line, stopping on the `if` line and examining `obj` and its properties?

Comment: Many thanks for the response. In fact - the 0 and the 1 after the objects in the screenshot above are the result of console.log(obj)....its logs as just a number, I'm presuming the array index.

Comment: You have the jQuery `each` parameters backward. Yet another reason to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$.each(withNull, function(idx, obj) {
```

The parameters to jQuery's `$.each` callback are in "backward" order.
It passes the index first, then the element.

Prefer to use

```
withNull.forEach(function(obj) {
```